# Recycling FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I'm building a FragmentPagerAdapter (The one with the small icons) which I want;

- To the first item in the middle (Horizontal) of the screen
- To swipe through it and make them go one 5th of the screen to the left/right

What would be the best way to achieve this?

This is a visual representation:

[image]

This is the code of the FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class NavigationPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public NavigationPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return NavigationFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return stores.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return 0.2f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you specify your question I can't really understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: There shouldbe 5 items horizontal to each other on the screen. The very first item should be in the middle and the second should be on the right of that first item. Any additional items should also be on the right as well. When swiped , the items will move to the left or right depending on wich side you swipe to. New items will be added to the screen and others wil fall of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood this right. Try to add the following configuration to your `ViewPager.

```
pager.setOffScreenPageLimit(4);
pager.setClipToPadding(false);
pager.setPageMargin(-500);
pager.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
pager.setFadingEdgeLength(20);
```

Feel free to customize the values and get your desired effect